My generative network is only producing noise instead of images
I've tried creating a network to generate images of numbers mimicking the MNIST data set. However, the network only produces noise as an output instead of a coherent image.
I've tried playing around with the loss functions and optimizers, but, the results are the same. I think it's a misunderstanding of how these types of networks work, but, I'd still like to know where I'm failing.
Here's the code for the image generator:
import numpy as np
import torch.utils
import torch.utils.data
import torch.utils.data.dataloader
from tqdm import tqdm
import torch
import torch.nn as nn #OOP
import torch.nn.functional as F #Functions (not oop based)
import torch.optim as optim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms, datasets

device = torch.device("cuda:0") #GPU

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() #Super = nn.Module, inherit the methods and modules from __init__
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10, 128) 
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 128)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(128, 128)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(128, 28*28)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc4(x)
        return (F.softmax(x, dim=1))

net = Net().to(device)

#Data
# 1 hot vector, index represents the number i want it to generate
# Generate a batch of 10 images
# Pass these images through the Number_Recogniser
# Compare the outputs using mean square loss
# With the loss update the gradients
def Data():
    return(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=64))

#Data sets
def DataSet(Data):
    One_Hot = []
    for data in Data:
        Ones = [0] * 10
        Ones[data] = 1
        Ones = torch.Tensor(Ones)
        Ones.view(-1, 10)
        Ones.to(device)
        One_Hot.append(Ones)
    return(One_Hot)

EPOCHS = 3000 # 300 for 30000 images

# Generate the labels
# Generate the images from the labels
# Pass the images through the Recogniser
# Take the ouput as a vector
# Use the mean square loss
# etc...

#Load the Number Recogniser
Number_Recogniser = torch.jit.load("model.pth")
Number_Recogniser.eval()


optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

for epoch in tqdm(range(EPOCHS)):
    rand = Data()
    dataset = DataSet(rand) #One hot vectors

    for data in dataset: #Loops over the batch
        y = data
        y = y.view(-1, 10)
        y = y.to(device)

        X = net(y)
        X = X.view(-1, 28*28)
        X = X.to(device)

        pred = Number_Recogniser(X)
        pred = pred.view(-1, 10)
        pred = pred.to(device)

        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    #print(loss)

image = X.view(-1, 28, 28)
image = torch.Tensor.cpu(image)
image = image.detach().numpy()
plt.imshow(image[0]).cmap("gray")
plt.show()

